# setOnClickListener on a imageview

Tags: java, android, android-imageview

I have a problem and I can not solve it.

I'm working on a floating view like **Facebook chathead** and I can not make the `ImageView` clickable to make it to open a black new activity and close the chat head in that same service.

Here is my code for the `FloatingViewService`

```
public class FloatingViewService extends Service {

    private WindowManager mWindowManager;
    private ImageView mImgFloatingView;
    private boolean mIsFloatingViewAttached = false;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        //Not use this method
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        if(!mIsFloatingViewAttached){
            mWindowManager.addView(mImgFloatingView,    n      mImgFloatingView.getLayoutParams());
        }
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        mWindowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

        mImgFloatingView = new ImageView(this);
        mImgFloatingView.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

        final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new     WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

        params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;

        mWindowManager.addView(mImgFloatingView, params);

        mImgFloatingView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            private int initialX;
            private int initialY;
            private float initialTouchX;
            private float initialTouchY;

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        initialX = params.x;
                        initialY = params.y;
                        initialTouchX = event.getRawX();
                        initialTouchY = event.getRawY();
                        return true;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        return true;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        params.x = initialX + (int) (event.getRawX() - initialTouchX);
                        params.y = initialY + (int) (event.getRawY() - initialTouchY);
                        mWindowManager.updateViewLayout(mImgFloatingView, params);
                        return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        mIsFloatingViewAttached = true;

        mImgFloatingView.setClickable(true);
        mImgFloatingView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent int1 = new     Intent(FloatingViewService.this,CrniProzor.class);
                startActivity(int1);

            }
        });
        }

    public void removeView() {
        if (mImgFloatingView != null){
            mWindowManager.removeView(mImgFloatingView);
            mIsFloatingViewAttached = false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onDestroy", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        super.onDestroy();
        removeView();
    }
}
`
```

and `MainActivity`

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    private Button mBtnShowView;
    private boolean mIsFloatingViewShow; //Flag variable used to identify if the Floating View is visible or not

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mBtnShowView = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_show_floating_view);
        mBtnShowView.setOnClickListener(this);
        mIsFloatingViewShow = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.btn_show_floating_view:
                if(mIsFloatingViewShow){
                    hideFloatingView();
                    mIsFloatingViewShow = false;
                    mBtnShowView.setText(R.string.show_floating_view);
                }
                else{
                    showFloatingView();
                    mIsFloatingViewShow = true;
                    mBtnShowView.setText(R.string.hide_floating_view);
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    private void showFloatingView() {
        startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FloatingViewService.class));
    }

    private void hideFloatingView() {
        stopService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FloatingViewService.class));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
    if ((Math.abs(initialTouchX - event.getRawX()) < 5) && (Math.abs(initialTouchY - event.getRawY()) < 5)) {
        Toast.makeText(FloatingViewService.this, "CLICK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    return true;
```